# Регулярное выражение, точное соответствие

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как сделать проверку числа от 2 до бесконечности?

```
^category/page-(?P<page>[0-9]+)$
```

То есть если в строке page-0 или page-1 то это не должно подходить под регулярку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
^category/page-(?![01]$)(?P<page>[0-9]+)$
               ^^^^^^^^^
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/l6hTrv/1).

Если числа типа `001` должны отфильтровываться, добавьте `0*` -> `(?!0*[01]$)`.

```
^category/page-(?!0*[01]$)(?P<page>[0-9]+)$
                  ^^
```

[Ещё одно демо](https://regex101.com/r/l6hTrv/2).

Шаблон `(?![01]$)` — блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который не возвращает совпадение, если сразу после текущей позиции (т.е. после дефиса) находится  `0` или `1` (`[01]`), после которых сразу следует конец строки (`$`). `0*` находит ноль и более знаков `0`.

Comment: как вариант `([3-9]|\d{2,})`

Comment: Спасибо мастер, полчаса мучился...

Comment: @Wiktor а без нуля впереди как-то можно сделать?

Comment: Я, кажется, об этом уже написал. Демо - https://regex101.com/r/l6hTrv/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew я задал вопрос раньше чем вы написали. Спасибо, все так как нужно было.

Comment: @Владимир Мне кажется, что я обновил ответ, когда написал *Если числа типа 001 должны отфильтровываться, добавьте `0*` -> `(?!0*[01]$).`* Потом я уже просто добавил вариант в ответ.